# How to make my program output the word Sixteen for the number 16 instead of sixSixteen

Tags: c#

Current student learning C#. The assignment is to convert numbers to their text equivalent, ranging from 0 to 999. Ex. 321 = Three hundred twenty one.

The problem: When I input a number like 16 it outputs sixSixteen.

Question: How do I ignore the digit1 out put when using specific numbers like 10, 11, 12, 13, etc.

```
    using System;

namespace Assignment_4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a whole number between 0 and 999: ");
            int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            int digit1 = num / 100;
            int digit2 = (num / 10) % 10;
            int digit3 = num % 10;

            if (num < 0 || num > 999) {
                Console.WriteLine("Number must be a whole number between 0 and 999.");

            }



            switch (digit1)
            {

                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                case 5:
                case 6:
                case 7:
                case 8:
                case 9:
                    Console.Write(digit1 + " hundred ");
                    break;
            }

            switch (digit2)
            {
                case 0:
                    Console.Write("and ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.Write("twenty ");
                    break; 
                case 3:
                    Console.Write("thirty ");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.Write("forty ");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Console.Write("fifty ");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Console.Write("sixty ");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    Console.Write("seventy ");
                    break;
                case 8:
                    Console.Write("eighty ");
                    break;
                case 9:
                    Console.Write("ninety ");
                    break;
            }

            switch (digit3)
            {
                case 2:
                    Console.Write("two");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.Write("three");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.Write("four");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Console.Write("five");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Console.Write("six");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    Console.Write("seven");
                    break;
                case 8:
                    Console.Write("eight");
                    break;
                case 9:
                    Console.Write("nine");
                    break;
            }

            switch (num)
            {
                case 10:
                    Console.Write("Ten");
                    break;
                case 11:
                    Console.Write("Eleven");
                    break;
                case 12:
                    Console.Write("Twelve");
                    break;
                case 13:
                    Console.Write("Thirteen");
                    break;
                case 14:
                    Console.Write("Fourteen");
                    break;
                case 15:
                    Console.Write("Fifteen");
                    break;
                case 16:
                    Console.Write("Sixteen");
                    break;
                case 17:
                    Console.Write("Seventeen");
                    break;
                case 18:
                    Console.Write("Eighteen");
                    break;
                case 19:
                    Console.Write("Nineteen");
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need an `if` condition after the `digit1` logic.  Take a look at the last two digits as a number.  If the number is between 10 and 19 inclusive, switch on the number.  If not, follow you current digit2 and digit3 logic.  Be happy it isn't in French (the numbers between 60 and 79 and between 80 and 99 are like English's 0-19).  Also follow @MichaelRandall's suggestions

Comment: In your code, `digi1` is the first digit from left when number is larger than 100. For any number less than 100, `digi1` is 0. Does your code work as you intended? Or you were meant to be `digi2`?

Answer (score 1):

With `16` as an example and following your code; you are converting them to `digit1`, `digit2`, and `digit3` with calculations and then doing `Console.Write` on each digit, and then finally on switch with `num`

So,

```
num = 16
digit1 = 16 / 100 = 0
digit2 = (16 / 10) % 10 = 1
digit3 = 16 % 10 = 6
```

And based on your switch statements, it would output the following (note this is not valid c#, just an example)

```
switch(digit1) // (nothing)
switch(digit2) // (nothing)
switch(digit3) // six
switch(num)    // Sixteen
```

Giving you your `sixSixteen` because of `digit3` and `num`

It wouldn't be right for me to finish the assignment for you, but at least I can point out what your code is currently doing so you can make adjustments from there.

Answer (score 0):

As you have said to ignore the 0-9 numbers

This is how it works for me

```
//this will check between 0 - 9
if( input<10 && input >-1) {
   //print 0,1,2,3,4
}else{
   //continue your logics 10s,20s,
}
```